# How I do to put the default picture in android? (Splash-screen)

Tags: android, image, splash-screen

I'm developing an android application and I want to put a default picture. This is common  in iPhone apps; when the app starts, it shows the name of the developer and the name of the application (for example) with an image.

I think that is possible because apps like Facebook have these default screens before the application starts. How can I implement these?

Comment: it's called a splash screen and in Android world it's not that common to use splash screens , anyway , you can find many examples of splash screens , or just make a info activity with all the information that you want to show .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `onCreate()` method of your launch activity, try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Thread proceed = new Thread(){

        public void run()
        {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
                Intent next = new Intent("nextActivityIntentGoesHere");
                startActivity(next);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                finish();
            }

        }
        };
        proceed.start();
    }
```

Your `main.xml` can be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/welcomescreenpicture" >
</LinearLayout>
```

This will display the `welcomescreenpicture` for 5 seconds when the application launches.

Comment: Kazekage Gaara, he doesn't have enough rep to up vote yet. Let me upvote you for him ;)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a splash screen:

- [How to:Create a Splash-Screen for Android](http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html)
- [A simple Android Splash-Screen](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/a-simple-android-splash-screen/)

Comment: OK thanks, I named deafualt because in iPhone only you have to put the image with the name default and select the time..